# How to calculate clustered HC1 robust standard errors for fixed effects model?

Tags: r, statistics, panel-data

I want to calculate HC robust standard errors clustered by firm.

If I don't specify any particular clustering in heteroscedasticity corrected standard errors, at what level is it clustered by default?

```
model <- plm(dep ~ a *b + a + b + controls, index=c(firm, year), method='within', effect='individual')

vcovHC(model, type="HC1")
```

Comment: If no clusters are defined, one could say that each observation becomes a "cluster". `vcovHC` doesn't cluster at all, option `"HC1"` just uses white SEs corrected for small sample size (`"HC0"` are the pure white SEs). For clustering you need sth like `sandwich::vcovCL`.

Comment: thanks man... vcovHC(model, type = "HC1", cluster= c('group')) will do clustering at firm level, right?

Comment: I'm sure it's thought to be like that. However, it strongly depends on the model you're about to fit, obviously a method for also clustered standard errors might be involved in your problem. You should show the model.

Comment: model is kind of like model <- plm(dep ~ a *b + a + b +   controls, index=c(firm,year), method = 'within', effect='individual')

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for a fixed effects model, you want to calculate heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors with small sample correction aka ~"HC1"`.

Using `vcovHC` on a `"plm"` object dispatches `plm:::vcovHC.plm`, where by default `"group"` is considered for clustering. (It's a bit counterintuitive that we specify `"group"` even though the cluster could be called something else.)

**However,** it (currently, `v2.6.3`) seems to give wrong statistics, and I wouldn't necessarily trust it. Let's quickly compare `plm:::vcovHC.plm` with alternatives.

```
data("Produc", package="plm")
```

**plm**

```
plm_fit <- plm::plm(Y ~ X, df, index=c('clus', 'time'), model='within', effect='twoways')
coef(summary(plm_fit, vcov=plm::vcovHC(plm_fit, type='HC1')))
coef(summary(plm_fit, vcov=plm::vcovHC(plm_fit, type='HC1', cluster='group')))
#    Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)
# X 0.4836304  0.2404504 2.011353 0.04508879
```

**[LSDV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174243/163114)**

```
lm_fit <- lm(Y ~ X + as.factor(clus) + as.factor(time), df)
lmtest::coeftest(lm_fit, vcov.=sandwich::vcovCL(lm_fit, cluster= ~ clus, type='HC1'))[2, ] 
#   Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|) 
# 0.48363045 0.26082212 1.85425394 0.06458153
```

**[wild bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Wild_bootstrap)**

```
set.seed(42)
summary(fwildclusterboot::boottest(lm_fit, clustid=c("clus"), B=9999, param="X"))
# boottest.lm(object = lm_fit, param = "X", B = 9999, clustid = c("clus"))
#   
#  Hypothesis: 1*X = 0
#  Observations: 387
#   Bootstr. Type: rademacher
#  Clustering: 1-way
#  Confidence Sets: 95%
#  Number of Clusters: 43
#  
#      term estimate statistic p.value conf.low conf.high
# 1 1*X = 0    0.484     1.854   0.056   -0.014     0.974
```

As we can see, the `plm:::vcovHC.plm` *t*-statistic is quite high and does not agree with established methods (try also different data).

As a convenient alternative, `lfe::felm` could be used, where clusters can be specified in the function call and the clustered standard errors appear to be more correct:

**felm**

```
coef(summary(lfe::felm(Y ~ X | clus + time | 0 | clus, df)))
#    Estimate Cluster s.e.  t value   Pr(>|t|)
# X 0.4836304    0.2432968 1.987821 0.05337641
```

Note that, in contrast to you, I have calculated two-way fixed effects, but this should also apply to your case.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Y = c(1.49174803034355, 1.49082343612826, 0.314097296389439, 
0.159346424264773, 0.777727960043061, 2.27104659892306, 1.07194507030165, 
0.459787236071797, 1.79522237356738, 0.38796255155268, 3.9717496156838, 
1.47000747891296, 2.48750071648911, 2.45237377400588, 2.237564524963, 
4.92583334910772, 1.00609520958128, 4.02014216565053, -0.177951088240575, 
-1.64825493708699, -0.601154331165537, 0.611239109846117, -0.998299917029293, 
-1.7885803819251, -0.0975296100298626, 0.984986053080225, -0.526316584544807, 
-1.71723763630578, -1.57063166179997, -0.793263678303983, -0.644092930841902, 
0.241341606975536, 1.35198911536743, -0.368809534760138, -1.46184791221506, 
1.29278012797767, 0.723408262207712, 2.2740070027646, -2.05604610780816, 
0.33822236520895, 2.50259089314923, 1.34154788603862, -1.01822211676808, 
1.58953755491299, -1.02875655277924, 0.850325383493099, 3.3488403840431, 
1.09608581669278, 2.7054762381336, 1.12574031703083, -1.04434831016523, 
0.158799354439072, 0.0731280352079167, 0.736097544700938, -1.76286430991729, 
-1.38149207531708, -1.71601985644626, 1.54809923277799, -3.39155961269454, 
-1.80117603040702, -0.625385370895466, 1.20401581244301, -1.13156560174762, 
2.95720604634241, -1.42938901981909, 3.34833883187238, 0.0614435370697493, 
0.615954844289406, -0.785038472934207, 1.28585707429456, 3.78659621077709, 
4.57951866115277, -0.748905321965872, 1.77229131026941, 3.08299147505921, 
0.509901594589063, 0.476713354602531, 0.277491808386503, 1.69810146742559, 
2.87304430538679, 2.02272792218214, 0.338123851665516, -0.704346979419049, 
0.472767104046156, -0.918737292392658, -0.632824737520819, 1.42009467640669, 
0.583288048015691, 0.344004569035102, -0.616128950140769, 1.11879943306165, 
1.66082325674087, -1.66290745628116, -0.225558838249109, -0.053505480308672, 
-1.28530830956508, -1.700212354975, -0.206338813308813, 0.742017389875334, 
2.55179943666739, -2.79191156194356, -0.993249576465555, -0.37037690025692, 
-2.24456489613489, -1.05176083995068, -1.00536305140978, -0.952959431820498, 
-3.05007337441189, -0.00338180248581516, -1.22455555539049, 1.84977797522718, 
0.939984490063607, -2.49529896296382, -0.380847844463749, -1.34832958809341, 
1.18404712841019, -0.290155722871786, -0.245753245667289, 1.29023425566867, 
0.661732571126717, 0.191477929941033, 3.38802785771415, -0.526246083026748, 
-0.195180463291803, -1.85186520114037, 0.422134258576091, 2.10926076105257, 
-2.45780590423763, 0.207265504346694, -1.19849917613251, 2.83516604780828, 
2.47957541324549, 1.22517483845413, 2.8019087612459, -0.708519660874986, 
1.07333836283621, -1.12561100112971, 0.0139837964427286, -0.982471593076287, 
-0.939759073814961, 0.248970611590601, -2.32447475851561, -0.90597776284819, 
-0.138394351342535, 0.404100723499759, 0.948559961531776, 0.226525319248101, 
3.0811423428166, 2.02779397740825, 5.21310434354964, -0.391053497128417, 
2.02688242278972, 3.87985409462045, 1.9211665758788, -0.0774953863416881, 
-0.237411155442983, 1.44341380592848, 3.29232450507269, 2.31179572368755, 
-1.71823107546202, 0.373158342204809, 1.40265205100963, -0.356721845891128, 
3.0315495581868, -1.83021434467659, 2.18378095576366, 1.43510743270427, 
1.06083983836095, 1.30000759489722, 2.21709537181066, 2.43949606309451, 
-0.1842261633815, -2.78506789464656, -1.97716142977856, -2.28948192254765, 
1.39007563105754, -0.450382690438105, 0.335936196362243, -2.28118698280083, 
-0.871539939512476, 2.25729403816272, 1.05547021508302, 1.23595337564864, 
1.0924832697628, 3.08960144749327, 0.265159497058315, 2.42788184797682, 
2.69145969834372, -0.597400777830574, 1.6938820727745, 1.61730328283039, 
3.26794836755541, 3.01080843342182, 1.62496877616786, 1.5738567269579, 
0.478435763940155, 1.25879982387903, 0.0701181741182104, -1.31145134768354, 
-1.68024273833644, 1.35564232306986, 1.70907724006424, -0.62128124868631, 
-1.55910246971228, -0.201050786726867, 3.44828913250509, 3.04420963331979, 
-1.18836699504093, 0.98272321806575, 3.80934184998198, 1.49812118126188, 
3.85457703357755, 0.988191976187003, 2.30036853575906, 1.81397250849382, 
6.17727654124204, 1.00169961909999, -2.21959653754997, -1.55559321244887, 
-0.0190172728913721, -3.36550408062016, -3.24823458587787, -2.16505647290807, 
-1.04451353785273, 1.25854612461907, -1.42412070469112, -0.632250335703772, 
-0.96500771901439, -1.97584430077941, 1.06004519338894, -2.83982294576359, 
-1.24230345106736, -1.61276054614704, -0.327323063691096, 2.02026810209445, 
0.296077332787956, 1.50054675285368, 0.59786250167299, -1.27261274035996, 
-0.485301664424986, 1.42314628484903, -2.67462177721486, 0.119505767952625, 
1.02182776936611, 2.57727356146994, 2.36687020317506, 1.75078000166229, 
3.38908987355581, -1.07215059205605, 2.48687067359171, -1.10997544094955, 
2.17298681026749, 0.874675866640857, 2.43197583776293, 0.906752197774744, 
-1.46660864496931, -2.24838463816107, 1.40770839932662, 0.546255185413357, 
0.114439047590734, 0.308610686852466, -0.413858687156799, 0.2402881124365, 
-0.95756766386402, -2.66223481180998, 0.226230031428551, 1.86969103356546, 
3.14652029748696, 0.329868628373377, 0.189004428421379, 1.97018340815427, 
0.720558428705733, 0.0164988614948769, -2.18112115756507, -1.16671250670762, 
1.12522593059621, -1.73176369992539, 2.29256744524201, -1.54176424077401, 
0.383240307855599, 0.867241783113517, 0.631150439937289, 0.865604705147437, 
1.66998973981833, 0.410066344321568, 0.243120477239532, 0.925289416133071, 
0.012592102290539, 2.41535467844496, -3.06532608431518, 1.70912773604766, 
-0.26921980354653, 0.595515241375289, 1.48260289736466, 1.33733276206916, 
-1.06900021684201, 2.48736128576119, -1.36593796271524, 2.3125507137345, 
0.367475505302975, -1.96467126190527, -1.64791614271238, 1.35737456266259, 
4.32876360476172, 1.34004043896507, 2.55161454178869, 0.50931799024147, 
-1.72089224769206, 0.539812139033077, -0.245872290483745, -0.32148886558538, 
0.619711895109556, 0.206686693200129, -1.70265579792275, -0.158001427022335, 
0.459428833421457, 2.62304356122207, 1.00522769351016, 2.28939391635689, 
2.40929274443458, 1.12235587807011, 2.44132366536701, 2.47684961750435, 
1.21304954876916, 2.04640141286051, 2.63593328421236, -0.696747744665241, 
-0.722488756401092, 1.25058238901514, -1.00068491924347, -0.411077327685348, 
1.45550746545174, -0.658978900737571, -1.00922868471967, 2.9105807344552, 
-0.43204633349781, -0.241167424889289, -2.58584579598567, 3.14286521353844, 
2.30623429033903, 2.52867982085648, 3.29210051226344, -0.336453417099218, 
-1.8582457887733, 0.715195438529871, 1.6042640965065, -2.52769311480167, 
-1.13116108248986, -0.599646365702945, -2.15791606599506, 0.972810420166205, 
1.59910510782794, 4.38697290530464, 2.39190193498343, 3.45018425773523, 
4.9220510730853, 2.86317442168188, 3.98771117204694, 2.80318522326581, 
0.0530830614059505, 1.85162567090321, 2.78707770225205, 2.55384039353425, 
1.46647391684788, -0.124525275816383, 2.56973340148059, 0.236720413414737, 
-0.317743881224743, 2.52733628910914, -2.10630913540531, 0.0566004810848823, 
-0.216507135534113, -2.39005175639272, 1.5059051517228, -1.28177414620545, 
1.56525949772855, -1.09344138921679, -1.20718174928978, 0.02319378963847, 
-0.469234505866541, -0.511556928042829, -1.28027051653858, -1.8125622613834, 
0.95541807454018, -1.07854390850658, -2.14331139458961, -0.857390882973856
), X = c(0.159022381762043, 0.304097996791825, 0.0175483247730881, 
0.996552679222077, 0.804393312660977, 0.086580601753667, 0.869933269685134, 
0.554585863370448, 0.421378421830013, 0.0676368190906942, 0.56143795652315, 
0.0707218942698091, 0.211391938850284, 0.54962041345425, 0.481981448363513, 
0.159469854552299, 0.149578995071352, 0.499272880377248, 0.940564878052101, 
0.334231326589361, 0.188434329582378, 0.269716178299859, 0.530744078103453, 
0.021450228523463, 0.7987603074871, 0.11033510020934, 0.53979828581214, 
0.571233897469938, 0.618951546959579, 0.714853693498299, 0.123300578678027, 
0.311049618758261, 0.945739162620157, 0.500025092391297, 0.135230499086902, 
0.869257820537314, 0.205049612093717, 0.92504589096643, 0.886753598228097, 
0.136295825242996, 0.785349442157894, 0.453303414164111, 0.135742419399321, 
0.885221036849543, 0.336713540134951, 0.319274115143344, 0.403782814741135, 
0.479077307041734, 0.367901820223778, 0.465690567623824, 0.0498921528924257, 
0.187356711598113, 0.982659413712099, 0.328274069586769, 0.170996390515938, 
0.488254894502461, 0.0186874116770923, 0.339485083706677, 0.0296633755788207, 
0.867228663060814, 0.731707599712536, 0.315260796807706, 0.386454011779279, 
0.332445990527049, 0.0897779711522162, 0.757055602502078, 0.6029684972018, 
0.145399972563609, 0.0325174834579229, 0.483768141595647, 0.444569527870044, 
0.060385589953512, 0.327506022062153, 0.878429047297686, 0.930604886263609, 
0.392178456997499, 0.158846774837002, 0.319947601063177, 0.30696562025696, 
0.107811254449189, 0.979334303410724, 0.496903428109363, 0.0930746719241142, 
0.211773658171296, 0.930500746238977, 0.296846406767145, 0.653218248859048, 
0.901070477906615, 0.990795793244615, 0.430333221331239, 0.393776922253892, 
0.141908895457163, 0.279806696344167, 0.56482222257182, 0.935139505425468, 
0.358400145079941, 0.842007180908695, 0.722409214358777, 0.750735989306122, 
0.92398845218122, 0.00237810681574047, 0.160429914947599, 0.399272951297462, 
0.675319577334449, 0.480372016318142, 0.533828780753538, 0.316950157284737, 
0.814757590182126, 0.292219521244988, 0.409132091328502, 0.0909183076582849, 
0.798596638021991, 0.359785249689594, 0.0404875767417252, 0.0410863398574293, 
0.954434238374233, 0.373341244878247, 0.806419667555019, 0.91005900898017, 
0.440076212864369, 0.57633650302887, 0.0736677951645106, 0.164627394406125, 
0.73989077587612, 0.475711012724787, 0.68552095326595, 0.951514942804351, 
0.497464487561956, 0.470500626601279, 0.56019195006229, 0.652510120533407, 
0.279573498759419, 0.979907589498907, 0.643864108016714, 0.58257843577303, 
0.615871025947854, 0.925140294479206, 0.390022895298898, 0.28791968501173, 
0.0907359647098929, 0.322033904027194, 0.758270112564787, 0.104412929620594, 
0.710277852602303, 0.966477383626625, 0.201491226209328, 0.108488654484972, 
0.0554021787829697, 0.829723515082151, 0.58119775657542, 0.470092375297099, 
0.365014120005071, 0.280124627286568, 0.599715854972601, 0.818569612922147, 
0.0978322804439813, 0.96368952607736, 0.168736443389207, 0.0860834058839828, 
0.86121069570072, 0.524790602037683, 0.656810875283554, 0.229519372805953, 
0.72122603142634, 0.490750394994393, 0.965255592484027, 0.906942480476573, 
0.551250527845696, 0.075599099509418, 0.0227000112645328, 0.513239527819678, 
0.630726151634008, 0.418771624332294, 0.879265945171937, 0.107987073017284, 
0.980278696399182, 0.264966631308198, 0.0842775232158601, 0.385907175717875, 
0.124895827146247, 0.581554221687838, 0.240149608114734, 0.721887888619676, 
0.145928690675646, 0.15283877030015, 0.259222670225427, 0.777886260068044, 
0.426466299686581, 0.0600483361631632, 0.1148325370159, 0.48275689734146, 
0.979173583909869, 0.811516786925495, 0.542912817094475, 0.0723670870065689, 
0.46648524608463, 0.33990564593114, 0.689918605145067, 0.514157372061163, 
0.514923015609384, 0.545514354016632, 0.447457330068573, 0.0838848403654993, 
0.930133691756055, 0.0164481862448156, 0.414092399412766, 0.226976093370467, 
0.0996405873447657, 0.482923875097185, 0.650128671433777, 0.92132977838628, 
0.362601807108149, 0.85513499006629, 0.300906151533127, 0.465662425151095, 
0.142730664927512, 0.80771899363026, 0.665807631798089, 0.0619409799110144, 
0.430925568332896, 0.396855081431568, 0.696956751402467, 0.659319650614634, 
0.407350709661841, 0.306920220376924, 0.255107345059514, 0.672568153357133, 
0.8943934335839, 0.845736156217754, 0.392901856917888, 0.0790505399927497, 
0.82842305698432, 0.0728918248787522, 0.114762677578256, 0.6399842700921, 
0.320566200185567, 0.1887495261617, 0.393829641165212, 0.86202601599507, 
0.347911406541243, 0.00143389846198261, 0.911284453701228, 0.951723448932171, 
0.49091898300685, 0.463651715312153, 0.596472046803683, 0.906050957273692, 
0.173001179005951, 0.785881076706573, 0.232934384606779, 0.577048209030181, 
0.840877033304423, 0.132203776855022, 0.895891189575195, 0.45013734116219, 
0.894142537843436, 0.248545180540532, 0.0836952936369926, 0.0486410746816546, 
0.979815867030993, 0.484167741145939, 0.845393033931032, 0.416293604532257, 
0.489342542830855, 0.183287817519158, 0.759161467896774, 0.305143302539364, 
0.165678247110918, 0.0328091429546475, 0.13650520821102, 0.177136411424726, 
0.519560450455174, 0.811120785074309, 0.11536201252602, 0.893421786604449, 
0.575352881103754, 0.146572394296527, 0.902805796358734, 0.253002469427884, 
0.150597600266337, 0.76854715985246, 0.230123331071809, 0.305399328004569, 
0.518569612177089, 0.334599666763097, 0.154434968251735, 0.266369568649679, 
0.350754616782069, 0.578458378789946, 0.808601795230061, 0.933270314941183, 
0.833863337524235, 0.127002774504945, 0.649453951511532, 0.690351657569408, 
0.0320448244456202, 0.920489149866626, 0.478468887042254, 0.266520578414202, 
0.856510716257617, 0.229146477766335, 0.79194687330164, 0.646774860331789, 
0.424334690673277, 0.0950682680122554, 0.00346770393662155, 0.531133668962866, 
0.524307115934789, 0.213185554603115, 0.7169320799876, 0.961343576200306, 
0.518266599625349, 0.174528022296727, 0.562540134880692, 0.759258169680834, 
0.666971337515861, 0.224872923223302, 0.345849762437865, 0.319831759901717, 
0.904898397624493, 0.199198380112648, 0.68096301658079, 0.137517758645117, 
0.10699468688108, 0.0928593957796693, 0.916448955191299, 0.277060435852036, 
0.885793877299875, 0.772864649537951, 0.795051236171275, 0.205673593096435, 
0.0481933229602873, 0.0388159311842173, 0.284574129851535, 0.348809832474217, 
0.737453325418755, 0.251663581235334, 0.517437003087252, 0.759444722672924, 
0.636084527941421, 0.2039406853728, 0.993045282084495, 0.000405043363571167, 
0.206570025067776, 0.634028090629727, 0.0172918252646923, 0.0267354713287205, 
0.60784059506841, 0.570541352732107, 0.245853347936645, 0.919525086414069, 
0.672216201666743, 0.645450439304113, 0.208285454660654, 0.480617735767737, 
0.986518583260477, 0.993119847727939, 0.450774036580697, 0.714848786126822, 
0.316561612533405, 0.833687560632825, 0.433975581545383, 0.995992258191109, 
0.805811213329434, 0.486242167418823, 0.538772000931203, 0.341039908351377, 
0.0520156044512987, 0.458723113173619, 0.498156590387225, 0.282764225266874, 
0.776445082388818, 0.3038527618628, 0.515551181975752, 0.477950773201883, 
0.768852224573493, 0.163928855676204, 0.441774149890989, 0.523407669737935, 
0.476919188629836, 0.524643287761137, 0.685228247195482, 0.351792022120208, 
0.839631285285577, 0.921913691563532, 0.106309621362016, 0.206528918119147
), clus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L
), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43"
), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-387L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Note that for your `plm` example you fit a one-way model while comparing it to two way models of other statistical packages, hence the coefficent and statistics are different. For a for a two-way FE model with `plm` use `plm_fit_tw <- plm::plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, data=Produc, index=c("state","year"), effect = "twoways")`.

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks for the pointer, fixed! I also used better data with a not so tiny effect size.

Comment: I do not think `plm::vcovHC` for HC1 gives wrong results. The difference to LSDV via `lm` + `sandwich::vcovCL` is small and rather seems to stem from the difference in degrees of freedom of FE model estimated via `plm` and LSDV via `lm`? No idea what `felm` does. Standard errors are involved to reconcile between packages due to many options/defaults, there are a few entries on SO and X-valides about the topics.

Comment: @Helix123 Notice the parentheses "try also different data" before judging the difference.  I spent some time on this answer, and `plm::vcovHC` can really throw weird results. There're also the _wild_ results you didn't mention that confirm LSDV in a way.